# mac save dialog not showing up for TextEdit/Word/Powerpoint/Excel

Tags: macos

I'm facing the weirdest issue and have spent hours googling a solution but returned empty-handed. I have a Mac early 2015 laptop with OS X Sierra(10.12.5) installed on it. Whenever I try to save a word/ppt/xls/txt file with Word/Powerpoint/Excel/TextEdit, the dialog box doesn't show up. There's no confirmation of whether it's been saved or not and I have lost hours of work because of this issue. Has anyone here faced this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: I know this is kind of the obvious one, but is the dialog box still not showing up after a reboot?

Comment: yeah, it's not showing up

Comment: What happens if you Save As...  ?

Comment: Nothing ... no dialog box shows up

Comment: I have the same issue on a 2019 Macbook Pro running macOS Monterey V. 12.0.1, while saving from Firefox, Preview, etc. Neither rebooting nor keyboard shortcuts help. I wonder if there is a solution yet.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/432277/56087) to a similar problem work for your case?

Answer (score 1):

- Step1: Open a textEdit and add some text into that (fig1)

[image]

- Step2: press `cmd+s` and the following window will popup(fig2)

[image]

- Step3: enter filename and specify the location to save (fig3)

[image]

- Step4: press save button at the bottom of the window
- Step5: Now this text document is saved and the `- Edited` in the
  title is disappeared(fig4)

[image]

from now onwards when you want to save some text or documents you can press `cmd+s` and for conformation you can check whether `- Edited` is there in the title or not. If `- Edited` is still there means the document or whatever it is not saved.
Hope this helps.
By the way, i am using Mavericks hopes its the same with OS X Sierra

Comment: I tried all ways to save but it doesn't work ... the window you mention won't show up